# jQuery script to modify <p> tag in HTML with user's input in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a simple jQuery script which will do the following:

1. I have HTML-code with `<p>` tag and `<textarea>` for user to type in.
2. User types text in `<textarea>` -> jQuery inserts it in `<p>`
       (class="youtyped") tag in HTML-code.

HTML-code:

```
<p class="youtyped"></p>

<textarea>Please type your text here</textarea>
```

Example of use:
User typed "Hello" in textarea, HTML-code will look like:

```
<p class="youtyped">Hello</p>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(){
    $('p.youtyped').text(this.value);
});
```

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(){
    $('p.youtyped').text(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="youtyped"></p>

<textarea>Please type your text here</textarea>
```

And if you want the value on Enter key then try,

```
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13)
       $('p.youtyped').text(this.value);
});
```

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13)
       $('p.youtyped').text(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="youtyped"></p>

<textarea>Please type your text here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
   $('p.youtyped').html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: You might want to describe what this code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(){
    $('p.youtyped').text($(this).val());
});
```